# Excel formula to return value if today's date is between a begging and the end of vacation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

So I have an excel sheet that contains list of employees who are required to attend the organizations events. Pretty much all employees except those who are on vacation.

1st Column / 2nd Colomun / 3rd Column / 4th Column
Employee name / Begging date of vacation / End Date of vacation / Attendance

How do I get the 4th column to detect so if that today's date is between the begging date and end date of the vacation and automatically return attend or does not attend?

Please tell me the formula which I would need to use.

Comment: Are you actually looking at today's date or the actual date of the event? Today's date shall keep on changing, but you shall have a specified date for your event that all employees are expected to attend, except those on vacation.

Comment: Even if you want today's date, just use a cell and refer to that cell rather than NOW or TODAY function in Excel. You can seamlessly insert today's date as a static value simply by pressing CTRL key followed by ; in single cell. This way you shall have a permanent or lasting record of proposed/expected attendance for that day, until you change the date value again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
=IF(AND(B2<=TODAY(), C2>=TODAY()), "Does Not Attend", "Attend")
```

But as mentioned in the comments, this checks against today, not any particular date of an event.  Do you have an 'EventDate' column or is the supervisor just looking at a daily roster to see who will be attending that day's events?

EDIT: If, for instance, your Events occur every Thursday, you could add columns for the next X Thursdays with the date in the top row.  Eg, in E1 you have 16-Nov-17, in F1 you have 23-Nov-17, in G1 30-Nov-17 etc (according to your local date format)

Then you would change the formula (in E2) to something like:

```
=IF(AND(B2<=E$1(), C2>=E$1()), "Does Not Attend", "Attend")
```

Copy this formula ACROSS the columns of Event dates and then DOWN the rows of employees

Comment: The event is constant in the sense that it occurs every Thursday. How would I translate that to a formula?